# Increase value of texbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

[image]

How can I increase and decrease  value of textbox by one on keyup/down or tap.
[example](http://jsfiddle.net/princefiddle/5aJzD/)

HTML:-

```
<div class="right-content" id="rc-0" style="height: 250px;">
  <div class="right-cont-main" id="rcm-0" style="height: 250px;">
    <div class="scroll-line" id="sl-0" style="height: 250px;">
      <div class="scroll-top" id="st-0"></div>
      <div class="scroll-mid" id="sm-0" style="height: 248px;"></div>
      <div class="scroll-bottom" id="sb-0"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="scroll-textbox" id="stb-0" style="margin-top: -138px;">
      <input type="text" class="scroll-textbox-input right-input" value="50" id="in-1" name="txt">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
 </div>        
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

do you mean something like:

```
$( document ).on( "keydown", ".right-input", function(ev) {
   if (ev.which == 38 || ev.which == 104) { //for up
        $this.val((parseInt($this.val()) + 1));
    } else if (ev.which == 40 || ev.which == 98) { //for down
        $this.val((parseInt($this.val()) - 1));
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I edited your source jsFiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/5aJzD/14/

```
if (e.which == 38 || e.which == 104) {
    height++;
} else if (e.which == 40 || e.which == 98) {
    height--;
}

height=parseInt(height);
$("#in-1").val(height);
```